# A expression/function to predict if the loop will run forever

Tags: python, python-2.7, prediction

I am writing a python game.

The game works as follows:

The computer sets up a battle between trainers with a random amount of chakra. In each battle, two trainers will pair off to battle. The trainer with fewer chakra will bet all their chakra, and the other trainer will match the bet. The winner will receive all of the bet chakra. The battle terminates if the chakra amount of both reaches the same level, as then the bet won't be fair. Due to a chakra curse, the trainer with less chakra always wins a round. Once a match begins, the pair of trainers will continue to battle and exchange chakra, until both of them have the same amount of chakra. Once that happens, both of them will think the game is not fair and back off.

This game can continue forever.
The player has 1 chance to predict the outcome, FOREVER or NOT FOREVER
But the problem is that the battle chakra amounts are random.
So in order to validate the player choice, I need to know the outcome.

How can I do so without using any external libraries?

EDIT - Here is my code

```
import random

print "WELCOME TO THE GUESSING GAME"

'''
...OTHER LEVELS...
'''

def curselevel():
    print "WELCOME TO THE DESTROYER LEVEL. PREDICT THE OUTCOME\n"
    o1 = random.randint(1,99)
    o2 = random.randint(1,99)
    print "The opponents are: ",o1,"CHAKRA vs ",o2,"CHAKRA!\n"
    print "ENTER CHOICE: F OR N\n"
    inp = raw_input("Choice: ")
    '''
    This is the part I am having trouble with.
    What to do next?
    '''
```

Comment: So this already received a negative vote. I am a beginner. I don't have experience in writing questions. Sorry.

Comment: You should provide relevant code for answerers to work from.

Comment: If you don't have experience writing questions, spend some time reading through the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and look at various (upvoted) questions, how those are written.

Comment: Without a clearer strategy for what happens in those battles, and at what point the game terminates, it will be difficult to calculate whether termination is guaranteed to happen in a finite number of iterations.

Comment: I am editing the question to include more clear description of the battles,

Comment: " continue to battle and exchange chakra". What does that mean, exactly? How much chakra can each trainer gain or lose in a single round? Without knowing that, it's impossible to tell when (or if) the chakra levels will ever come equal.

Comment: If you're a beginner why do you work with Python 2.7? Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020 and that was announced over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the algorithm to do this.
Cardinality Matching Algorithm from `September 6, 2003..`
Kudos to `D. Eppstein, UC Irvine`

```py
from math import gcd

"""UnionFind.py

Union-find data structure. Based on Josiah Carlson's code,
http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/215912
with significant additional changes by D. Eppstein.
"""

class UnionFind:
    """Union-find data structure.

    Each unionFind instance X maintains a family of disjoint sets of
    hashable objects, supporting the following two methods:

    - X[item] returns a name for the set containing the given item.
      Each set is named by an arbitrarily-chosen one of its members; as
      long as the set remains unchanged it will keep the same name. If
      the item is not yet part of a set in X, a new singleton set is
      created for it.

    - X.union(item1, item2, ...) merges the sets containing each item
      into a single larger set.  If any item is not yet part of a set
      in X, it is added to X as one of the members of the merged set.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new empty union-find structure."""
        self.weights = {}
        self.parents = {}

    def __getitem__(self, object):
        """Find and return the name of the set containing the object."""

        # check for previously unknown object
        if object not in self.parents:
            self.parents[object] = object
            self.weights[object] = 1
            return object

        # find path of objects leading to the root
        path = [object]
        root = self.parents[object]
        while root != path[-1]:
            path.append(root)
            root = self.parents[root]

        # compress the path and return
        for ancestor in path:
            self.parents[ancestor] = root
        return root
        
    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterate through all items ever found or unioned by this structure."""
        return iter(self.parents)

    def union(self, *objects):
        """Find the sets containing the objects and merge them all."""
        roots = [self[x] for x in objects]
        heaviest = max([(self.weights[r],r) for r in roots])[1]
        for r in roots:
            if r != heaviest:
                self.weights[heaviest] += self.weights[r]
                self.parents[r] = heaviest

import sys

def arbitrary_item(S):
    """
    Select an arbitrary item from set or sequence S.
    Avoids bugs caused by directly calling iter(S).next() and
    mysteriously terminating loops in callers' code when S is empty.
    """
    try:
        return next(iter(S))
    except StopIteration:
        raise IndexError("No items to select.")


def matching(G, initialMatching = None):
    """Find a maximum cardinality matching in a graph G.
    G is represented in modified GvR form: iter(G) lists its vertices;
    iter(G[v]) lists the neighbors of v; w in G[v] tests adjacency.
    For maximal efficiency, G and G[v] should be dictionaries, so
    that adjacency tests take constant time each.
    The output is a dictionary mapping vertices to their matches;
    unmatched vertices are omitted from the dictionary.

    We use Edmonds' blossom-contraction algorithm, as described e.g.
    in Galil's 1986 Computing Surveys paper.
    """

    # Copy initial matching so we can use it nondestructively
    # and augment it greedily to reduce main loop iterations
    matching = greedyMatching(G,initialMatching)

    def augment():
        """Search for a single augmenting path.
        Returns true if the matching size was increased, false otherwise.
        """

        # Data structures for augmenting path search:
        #
        # leader: union-find structure; the leader of a blossom is one
        # of its vertices (not necessarily topmost), and leader[v] always
        # points to the leader of the largest blossom containing v
        #
        # S: dictionary of blossoms at even levels of the structure tree.
        # Dictionary keys are names of blossoms (as returned by the union-find
        # data structure) and values are the structure tree parent of the blossom
        # (a T-node, or the top vertex if the blossom is a root of a structure tree).
        #
        # T: dictionary of vertices at odd levels of the structure tree.
        # Dictionary keys are the vertices; T[x] is a vertex with an unmatched
        # edge to x.  To find the parent in the structure tree, use leader[T[x]].
        #
        # unexplored: collection of unexplored vertices within blossoms of S
        #
        # base: if x was originally a T-vertex, but becomes part of a blossom,
        # base[t] will be the pair (v,w) at the base of the blossom, where v and t
        # are on the same side of the blossom and w is on the other side.

        leader = UnionFind()
        S = {}
        T = {}
        unexplored = []
        base = {}

        # Subroutines for augmenting path search.
        # Many of these are called only from one place, but are split out
        # as subroutines to improve modularization and readability.

        def blossom(v,w,a):
            """Create a new blossom from edge v-w with common ancestor a."""

            def findSide(v,w):
                path = [leader[v]]
                b = (v,w)   # new base for all T nodes found on the path
                while path[-1] != a:
                    tnode = S[path[-1]]
                    path.append(tnode)
                    base[tnode] = b
                    unexplored.append(tnode)
                    path.append(leader[T[tnode]])
                return path

            a = leader[a]   # sanity check
            path1,path2 = findSide(v,w), findSide(w,v)
            leader.union(*path1)
            leader.union(*path2)
            S[leader[a]] = S[a] # update structure tree

        topless = object()  # should be unequal to any graph vertex
        def alternatingPath(start, goal = topless):
            """Return sequence of vertices on alternating path from start to goal.
            The goal must be a T node along the path from the start to
            the root of the structure tree. If goal is omitted, we find
            an alternating path to the structure tree root.
            """
            path = []
            while 1:
                while start in T:
                    v, w = base[start]
                    vs = alternatingPath(v, start)
                    vs.reverse()
                    path += vs
                    start = w
                path.append(start)
                if start not in matching:
                    return path     # reached top of structure tree, done!
                tnode = matching[start]
                path.append(tnode)
                if tnode == goal:
                    return path     # finished recursive subpath
                start = T[tnode]

        def alternate(v):
            """Make v unmatched by alternating the path to the root of its structure tree."""
            path = alternatingPath(v)
            path.reverse()
            for i in range(0,len(path)-1,2):
                matching[path[i]] = path[i+1]
                matching[path[i+1]] = path[i]

        def addMatch(v, w):
            """Here with an S-S edge vw connecting vertices in different structure trees.
            Find the corresponding augmenting path and use it to augment the matching.
            """
            alternate(v)
            alternate(w)
            matching[v] = w
            matching[w] = v

        def ss(v,w):
            """Handle detection of an S-S edge in augmenting path search.
            Like augment(), returns true iff the matching size was increased.
            """

            if leader[v] == leader[w]:
                return False        # self-loop within blossom, ignore

            # parallel search up two branches of structure tree
            # until we find a common ancestor of v and w
            path1, head1 = {}, v
            path2, head2 = {}, w

            def step(path, head):
                head = leader[head]
                parent = leader[S[head]]
                if parent == head:
                    return head     # found root of structure tree
                path[head] = parent
                path[parent] = leader[T[parent]]
                return path[parent]

            while 1:
                head1 = step(path1, head1)
                head2 = step(path2, head2)

                if head1 == head2:
                    blossom(v, w, head1)
                    return False

                if leader[S[head1]] == head1 and leader[S[head2]] == head2:
                    addMatch(v, w)
                    return True

                if head1 in path2:
                    blossom(v, w, head1)
                    return False

                if head2 in path1:
                    blossom(v, w, head2)
                    return False

        # Start of main augmenting path search code.

        for v in G:
            if v not in matching:
                S[v] = v
                unexplored.append(v)

        current = 0     # index into unexplored, in FIFO order so we get short paths
        while current < len(unexplored):
            v = unexplored[current]
            current += 1

            for w in G[v]:
                if leader[w] in S:  # S-S edge: blossom or augmenting path
                    if ss(v,w):
                        return True

                elif w not in T:    # previously unexplored node, add as T-node
                    T[w] = v
                    u = matching[w]
                    if leader[u] not in S:
                        S[u] = w    # and add its match as an S-node
                        unexplored.append(u)

        return False    # ran out of graph without finding an augmenting path

    # augment the matching until it is maximum
    while augment():
        pass

    return matching

def greedyMatching(G, initialMatching=None):
    """Near-linear-time greedy heuristic for creating high-cardinality matching.
    If there is any vertex with one unmatched neighbor, we match it.
    Otherwise, if there is a vertex with two unmatched neighbors, we contract
    it away and store the contraction on a stack for later matching.
    If neither of these two cases applies, we match an arbitrary edge.
    """

    # Copy initial matching so we can use it nondestructively
    matching = {}
    if initialMatching:
        for x in initialMatching:
            matching[x] = initialMatching[x]

    # Copy graph to new subgraph of available edges
    # Representation: nested dictionary rep->rep->pair
    # where the reps are representative vertices for merged clusters
    # and the pair is an unmatched original pair of vertices
    avail = {}
    has_edge = False
    for v in G:
        if v not in matching:
            avail[v] = {}
            for w in G[v]:
                if w not in matching:
                    avail[v][w] = (v,w)
                    has_edge = True
            if not avail[v]:
                del avail[v]
    if not has_edge:
        return matching

    # make sets of degree one and degree two vertices
    deg1 = {v for v in avail if len(avail[v]) == 1}
    deg2 = {v for v in avail if len(avail[v]) == 2}
    d2edges = []
    def updateDegree(v):
        """Cluster degree changed, update sets."""
        if v in deg1:
            deg1.remove(v)
        elif v in deg2:
            deg2.remove(v)
        if len(avail[v]) == 0:
            del avail[v]
        elif len(avail[v]) == 1:
            deg1.add(v)
        elif len(avail[v]) == 2:
            deg2.add(v)

    def addMatch(v,w):
        """Add edge connecting two given cluster reps, update avail."""
        p,q = avail[v][w]
        matching[p] = q
        matching[q] = p
        for x in avail[v].keys():
            if x != w:
                del avail[x][v]
                updateDegree(x)
        for x in avail[w].keys():
            if x != v:
                del avail[x][w]
                updateDegree(x)
        avail[v] = avail[w] = {}
        updateDegree(v)
        updateDegree(w)

    def contract(v):
        """Handle degree two vertex."""
        u,w = avail[v]  # find reps for two neighbors
        d2edges.extend([avail[v][u],avail[v][w]])
        del avail[u][v]
        del avail[w][v]
        if len(avail[u]) > len(avail[w]):
            u,w = w,u   # swap to preserve near-linear time bound
        for x in avail[u].keys():
            del avail[x][u]
            if x in avail[w]:
                updateDegree(x)
            elif x != w:
                avail[x][w] = avail[w][x] = avail[u][x]
        avail[u] = avail[v] = {}
        updateDegree(u)
        updateDegree(v)
        updateDegree(w)

    # loop adding edges or contracting deg2 clusters
    while avail:
        if deg1:
            v = arbitrary_item(deg1)
            w = arbitrary_item(avail[v])
            addMatch(v,w)
        elif deg2:
            v = arbitrary_item(deg2)
            contract(v)
        else:
            v = arbitrary_item(avail)
            w = arbitrary_item(avail[v])
            addMatch(v,w)

    # at this point the edges listed in d2edges form a matchable tree
    # repeat the degree one part of the algorithm only on those edges
    avail = {}
    d2edges = [(u,v) for u,v in d2edges if u not in matching and v not in matching]
    for u,v in d2edges:
        avail[u] = {}
        avail[v] = {}
    for u,v in d2edges:
        avail[u][v] = avail[v][u] = (u,v)
    deg1 = {v for v in avail if len(avail[v]) == 1}
    while deg1:
        v = arbitrary_item(deg1)
        w = arbitrary_item(avail[v])
        addMatch(v,w)

    return matching
def willLoop(x, y):
    n = x+y
    n_tilde = n
    while n_tilde % 2 == 0:
        n_tilde = n_tilde / 2
    return (x % n_tilde) != 0

def bananaGraph(banana_list):
    G = {i: [] for i in range(len(banana_list))}
    for i, a in enumerate(banana_list):
        for j, b in enumerate(banana_list):
            if i != j and willLoop(a, b):
                G[i].append(j)
    return G

def solution(a,b):
    banana_list = [a,b]
    G = bananaGraph(banana_list)
    matches = matching(G)
    return len(banana_list) - len(matches)
```

Run the `solution` function with two chakra values to predict the outcome of the battle.

Code is reusable, perhaps.